# Dont show default text on two select options

Tags: jquery, select

Dont show text default in `value="beaches"` on `value="chill"`and other `value="chill"`. I want to display the default value [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6xrpLrht/)

```js
jQuery('#preference, #style').on('change', function() {
  // set reference to select elements
  var preference = jQuery('#preference');
  var style = jQuery('#style');

  // check if user has made a selection on both dropdowns
  if (preference.prop('selectedIndex') > 0 && style.prop('selectedIndex') > 0) {
    // remove active class from current active div element
    jQuery('.result.active').removeClass('active');

    // get all result divs, and filter for matching data attributes
    jQuery('.result').filter('[data-preference="' + preference.val() + '"][data-style="' + style.val() + '"]').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.result {
  display: none;
}

.result.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="preference">
  <option value="beaches">beaches</option>
  <option value="museums">museums</option>
  <option value="mountains">mountains</option>
</select>
<select id="style">
  <option value="chill">chill</option>
  <option value="fast-paced">fast-paced</option>
  <option value="both">both</option>
</select>

<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="chill">beaches and chill, show text Default</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="fast-paced">beaches and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="both">beaches and both</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="chill">museums and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="fast-paced">museums and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="both">museums and both</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="chill">mountains and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="fast-paced">mountains and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="both">mountains and both</div>
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're attempting to do here. Are you saying you want the text to be cleared when the first option from both selects are chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the text in the div if you select beaches and chill, just update your if:

```
if (preference.prop('selectedIndex') >= 0 && style.prop('selectedIndex') >= 0)
```

If you want to display without even clicking, call your function in `[$(document).ready();][1]`
See below:

```js
function check() {
  // set reference to select elements
  var preference = jQuery('#preference');
  var style = jQuery('#style');

  // check if user has made a selection on both dropdowns
  if (preference.prop('selectedIndex') >= 0 && style.prop('selectedIndex') >= 0) {
    // remove active class from current active div element
    jQuery('.result.active').removeClass('active');

    // get all result divs, and filter for matching data attributes
    jQuery('.result').filter('[data-preference="' + preference.val() + '"][data-style="' + style.val() + '"]').addClass('active');
  }
}

$(document).ready(check);

jQuery('#preference, #style').on('change', check);
```

```css
.result {
  display: none;
}

.result.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="preference">
  <option value="beaches">beaches</option>
  <option value="museums">museums</option>
  <option value="mountains">mountains</option>
</select>
<select id="style">
  <option value="chill">chill</option>
  <option value="fast-paced">fast-paced</option>
  <option value="both">both</option>
</select>

<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="chill">beaches and chill, show text Default</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="fast-paced">beaches and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="both">beaches and both</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="chill">museums and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="fast-paced">museums and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="both">museums and both</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="chill">mountains and chill</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="fast-paced">mountains and fast-paced</div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="both">mountains and both</div>
```

Or, you can use the same logic. Creating one empty option to your select tag:

```
<select id="preference">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="beaches">beaches</option>
  <option value="museums">museums</option>
  <option value="mountains">mountains</option>
</select>
<select id="style">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="chill">chill</option>
  <option value="fast-paced">fast-paced</option>
  <option value="both">both</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append an option without a value for a default text like so:

```
<select id="style">
    <option>default text</option>
    <option value="chill">chill</option>
    <option value="fast-paced">fast-paced</option>
    <option value="both">both</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
```

Example

```
<select>
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```